# Unable to generate typescript models using sequelize-auto

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, sequelize.js

I am dealing with a situation in which i need to use `sequelize` with an existing `MySQL` database, hence i figured it'd be better if I could generate the `Model`s for `sequelize` with some kind of generator,

Found [`sequelize-auto`](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) and successfully generated `Model`s into my code.

Reading their documentation they provide many optional flags to the generator command, one of them is `-z` or `--typescript` in order to generate the `Model`s as `typescript` files, unfortunately, the generated code is still in `js` format and the file are `.js` suffix.

Tried searching for others experiencing the same issues, found nothing :/

Any idea what am i missing?

My command:

```
sequelize-auto -h myDb -d database_name -u some_user -x some_password -p 3306 -e mysql -o src/models -C --typescript
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that the version of sequelize-auto you currently use isn't the latest version. You can for instance check if `.node_modules/sequelize-auto/lib/ts-helper.js` is present or not. In case it isn't, it clearly means your version of sequelize-auto doesn't match the current version on the repo.

A quick workaround to solve this is to do `yarn add https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto` which will basically use version currently present on the repo as a node module (instead of the latest stable release).

People are merging PRs concerning typescript in sequelize-auto as I write this, make sure to switch back to a stable release as soon as there is one with the changes you are looking for.